# Linked Server stops responding for particular login

Tags: sql-server, linked-server

We have an issue where the Linked Server does not work for the app team login but tests successfully when the DBA checks the connectivity. On investigating we found that the app login had some Killed/Rollback sessions which are causing this issue. The only resolution we have now is to Restart the instance.

Multiple sessions from the app login which are in Killed/Rollback and would not do anything (0 CPU Time and 0 Disk IO). This is a report login which extracts reports all day and sometimes this happens.

Is there any way to fix it without an instance restart?

Comment: Why are you restarting SQL Server if it's rolling back? When it comes back up again, it still has to finish the rollback. I think this is a red herring, and something else is blocking you.

Comment: On investigating we found that the app login had some Killed/Rollback sessions which are causing this issue--if you do not tell us the finding of your investigation, how do you expect help form others?

Comment: @RandolphWest : There are multiple sessions with 0 IO n CPU Time which can only get cleared after a restart.

Comment: @SqlWorldWide : These sessions are from App and from particular login which has multiple sessions. We have asked App team to check on this Killed/Rollback session issue. Any idea or have you seen anything like this?    Apologies but it was night and was asleep so replied early mornng

Comment: An application account can have multiple session, there is nothing wrong with that. If they are in killed/rolled back status you will need to let those rollback happen. Rebooting server will make it worse. It will start rollback from the beginning. You need to investigate why these were killed and rolling back.

Comment: @SqlWorldWide : These Killed/Rollback are ghost sessions doing nothing (0 IO, 0 CPU Time in sp_who2). Have sent the RCA to the app team to check why the app is doing this and find the reason. Thanks for your valuable points on this.

Answer (score 3):

Stop restarting SQL Server. Just stop doing that. If you have a particular problem with a particular process that is being killed and rolling back, *let it finish*. Then, find out what's causing that to happen. Use Extended Events, or a server-side trace, heck, even a third party tool like sp_WhoIsActive. Do *something*.

SQL Server has a transaction log. All modifications go in there. When these are committed, the changes go into the data file. When they are killed, they have to roll back.

That's just how it works. The rollback has to finish for the database to remain transactionally consistent.

Restarting SQL Server does not make this go faster. In fact, you could easily make things worse, possibly even taking the database offline or corrupting it.

Admittedly, this answer does not address your question, but there's not enough space in the comments to explain why you need to figure out what's causing the killed processes. It could be a DBA, it could be an automated process.

Bottom line: let SQL Server finish what it's doing. If it takes a long time to do something, killing the task will take just as long, if not longer, as that to roll back.

Comment: Well this is the last resort as these Killed/Rollback sessions do not process anything as mentioned 0 Disk IO and 0 CPU Time for long time. These are sessions that do few Select queries for fetching report and somehow there is some issue with App that it kills it and gets stuck.   Have notified this to App team and will be investigating further. Thank you for confirming that there is nothing a DBA can do in this case as its the app that is killing the processes.

Comment: It is not the last resort. Use the options I mentioned at the beginning of my answer. There's something else at play here. Don't think that because it says Microsoft on the software that rebooting is the right solution. It isn't.

Comment: Yes I agree with you :)   Have asked the App team to check this behavior of the app and find the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

I'm shamelessly [plagiarizing myself](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/68054/fix-linked-server-without-restarting-sql-server-instance/68223#68223) from a [different question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/68054/fix-linked-server-without-restarting-sql-server-instance), but I suspect the same scenario is happening here.

Depending on the statement the App Team is running and how you have your linked servers configured, you could be running into a situation where you have an [orphaned distributed transaction](http://web.archive.org/web/20151020034227/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/psssql/archive/2010/04/20/how-it-works-orphan-dtc-transaction-session-spid-2.aspx) sitting out there that you need to kill.  To identify if this is the case or not, first run the following query:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT request_owner_guid
FROM    sys.dm_tran_locks 
WHERE   request_session_id = -2
```

If this returns records, chances are good that you are in fact running into this very situation.  To kill these orphaned transactions, you have to run the following statement for each record returned by the query above:

```
KILL 'UOW'
```

***UOW*** is the request_owner_guid returned in the above query.

I've run into this situation with both linked server issues and jobs that are making calls externally from the SQL Server process.  In either case, I would find that an external process would interfere (e.g. network drop, process is killed or errors unexpectedly, etc.) and then the transaction wouldn't properly terminate at the SQL Server.  SQL Server won't know that the transaction has actually failed and things will just sit out there until you either walk through this process or bounce the server as you are already doing now.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Surely will check that when I have same issue again. Thank you